# Help police finding my iPhone

Tags: find-my-iphone

I have my iPhone 13 (iOS 16, no JB) stolen. I have marked it as lost in Locator app and reported to police and gave them IMEI's.

Maybe it is better now to erase the phone and turn the Lost mode off? So the thieves can use it, make calls and impersonate themselves to the police.

Is it a good idea?

Comment: Don't you see the location of the phone, wouldn't this be useful for the police?

Comment: @nohillside the phone seems to be turned off and appears in Locator maybe once in a month. Sure, the locations I report to the police.

Answer (score 6):

The police are not actively looking for your phone. You are. If they ever coincidentally come across a hoard of stolen phones they will check IMEI numbers. If one or more of the phones shows lock mode with contact details to the legitimate owner, their job becomes easier. This is a small chance, but a chance nevertheless.

If you release the phone from FindMy & reset it, the thief can then re-sell it, untraceably & in full working order. The new owner, though in possession of stolen property, will never know.
Bye bye phone for ever.

Comment: >>> untraceably
but how about tracing by IMEI's?

Comment: At what point is a random owner of a fully working phone, with no connection to the original thief except perhaps an eBay purchase, ever going to have their phone examined for its IMEI? Never. How many times have you ever been stopped in the street, or even at an airport, by an official wanting to check your phone's legitimacy? Never.

Comment: Is not there a police tool, monitoring cellular networks and notifying when one of IMEI's from a stolen list appears online?

Comment: No. Too much work. Some forces will track numbers known to be involved in crimes, but really the only thing that can be done is to get the phone company to add it to a blocklist - which of course means you can no longer track it by phone mast, only by wifi.